# Box-shadow falls outside container

Tags: html, css

I have a `.container` in that there are n number of (`left-block` and `right-block`) div's. 
But the `box-shadow` of elements floating to right side falls outside container.
Is it possible to bring the `box-shadow` inside `.container` instead of using `margin-right`

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ayiziNa/6/)

Comment: Why would you not want to use margin-right?

Comment: @ChrisP There will be n number of elements floating to right. so i dont want to use `margin-right`

Comment: So you want to show 10 pixels worth of shadow in 0 pixels worth of space?

Comment: Your going to need some sort of buffer, likely padding on the container.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `overflow:hidden` to your `.container`:

```css
.container {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[**Working JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/ayiziNa/9/).

Comment: @vishalkin in that case yes, you'll have to use `margin-right` on your `right-block` elements.

Answer (score 2):

You could add some padding to your container to compensate.

```
.container {
  /* ... */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

`border-box` will prevent your added padding from affecting your `width: 100%`.

http://jsbin.com/ayiziNa/14

Answer (score 1):

The only way to achieve explicitly what you have asked for is to add a right margin.

```
.right-block {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need it

```
.right-block {box-shadow: -10px 10px 5px #888888;}
```